# Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2978]

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a question please help me

thanks..

my cake php is 2.5.4  and i use xampp ver 3.2.1 , but i get  this error.

```
Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2978]
```

Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2956]

My veiw is:

```
public function edit($id=null) {
    if(!$id) {      
        $this->Session->setFlash('not found this job');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);

    }
    if(empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data=$this->Task->find(array('all',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id))));
    } else {            
        if($this->Task->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('updated');

            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('this up date has problem !!! ');
        }

    }
}
```

and my controller is:

```
public function edit($id=null) {
    if(!$id) {      
        $this->Session->setFlash('not found this job');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);

    }
    if(empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data=$this->Task->find(array('all',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id))));
    } else  {

        if($this->Task->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('updated');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('this up date has problem !!! ');
        }

    }


}
```

please help me

Comment: your model has an issue. please post that. you can probably remove the view and controller

Comment: Please post here also header of your Controller because we even can't guess whether you initialize your Model.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [**`Model::find()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) wrong, what should be passed as separate arguments is wrapped in an array.

It has to be

```
find('all', array('conditions' => /* ... */));
```

not

```
find(array('all', array('conditions' => /* ... */)));
```

Comment: In my case, I was doing `find($id)`, instead of `findById($id)`.